# button change name when pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to create a button that changes its value when it is pressed.

```
$("button").click( function() {
    valor = this.html();
    retorno = (valor == 'Exibir') ? 'Ocultar' : 'Exibir';
    this.html(retorno);
});
```

I'm having this message:

Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'html'

I appreciate any help.

Comment: That's a lot of globals…

Comment: As Quentin alluded to - you are polluting the global space by not declaring your variables as local within your function. Add "var" before these declrations to make them local.

Comment: Thank you all for explanation on globals. I did not know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
valor = $(this).html();
```

Answer (score 5):

`this` is an HTMLElementNode object, not a jQuery object.

```
valor = jQuery(this).html();
```

Answer (score 2):

`this` refers to the HTMLElementNode (window) object and is not an jquery object and as html is a jquery method it won't work.

So to make it a jquery object you need to wrap the `$` around it:

```
 $("button").click( function() {
     valor = $(this).html();
     retorno = (valor == 'Exibir') ? 'Ocultar' : 'Exibir';
     $(this).html(retorno);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this...

```
$("button").on('click', function() {
    valor = $(this).html();
    retorno = (valor == 'Exibir') ? 'Ocultar' : 'Exibir';
    $(this).html(retorno);
});
```

See this example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dJW3F/)

Answer (score 1):

`this` will refer to an HTMLElementNode, so you could do `valor = this.innerHTML` and avoid the jQuery call.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("button").click( function() {
     valor = $(this).html();
     retorno = (valor == 'Exibir') ? 'Ocultar' : 'Exibir';
     $(this).html(retorno);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
valor = jQuery(this).html();
```